# Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall

I have a dual booted laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I have seriously messed up my Ubuntu with several broken packagaes to the point where I can't use Python or upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. I want to remove Ubuntu completely and reinstall it (or install Ubuntu 18.04, either works well). I do not want to remove Windows

How can I do it? Most of the stuff online only talk about installing Ubuntu or removing it. Some of the sites talk about reinstalling Ubuntu keeping all data intact which is not desirable for me either. Any help would be great.

Comment: You haven't said if a desktop, server or other install. You can re-install Ubuntu using the "*something else*" option, selecting your existing partitions, ensuring you haven't selected *format* for any partition(s), then it'll note your additional packages, erase system directories, install, add back your additional packages, then ask to reboot. It won't touch user files (unless you selected format). This is especially useful for desktop re-installs.  (same can be used to change release too; ie. a fast upgrade).

Comment: @guiverc Yea I am talking about desktop installation. I do not care about the user files as I have a back-up. Would it work if I use Ubuntu18  in the USB flash drive while previously having Ubuntu 16?

Comment: If you do not want to keep anything, would do a format and clean install over your ubuntu partition.  Do check everything two or three times to make sure you are doing it on the right partition.  Can use any version you want, but 18.04 or 20.04 be recommended now.  16.04 will need upgrading next year.